# Wait a minute! Is Connie Willis implying that Verity Kindle is already....OW!

Tags: time-travel, connie-willis, to-say-nothing-of-the-dog

*(Spencer yells in pain as Valorum kicks him in the shin)*

Really funny SF is extremely rare, and I'm loath to pick apart a treasure such as Connie Willis's time travel farce *[To Say Nothing of the Dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Say_Nothing_of_the_Dog)*. But something has always been bothering me.

Our hero and heroine zip back and forth through time, eventually locating their monstrous McGuffin just in time to complete Lady Schrapnell's boondoggle. At which point, of course, they have to confess their undying love for each other.

In the final exchange between Ned and Verity:

> "I love you", I said, shaking my head. "If I'm fated to spend my life with you, does that mean you've decided to marry me?"
> "**I have to**," she said. "I just ran into Lady Schrapnell. She's decided what this cathedral needs is--"
> "A wedding?" I said.
> "**No, a christening**. So they can use the Purbeck marble baptismal font."

Now, I don't know about you, but that can imply a lot of different things. Most of the story happened in the Victorian Era, and Victorian circumlocution is definitely part of the plot. Such things did go on among the Victorians; otherwise, no-one would have understood *Madam Bovary*.

There are episodes of the book where the two secretly meet, to give each other updates on their efforts to Right the Timestream. But...

Am I just imagining things?

Comment: I know funny, and this isn't it ;-)

Comment: @Valorum I had to pick some name, and yours begins with a "V".

Comment: Is there a question here? OK, "Am I just imagining things?" is a question, but you haven't told us what it is that you are imagining.

Comment: @user14111 Have you read the book? The fact is, others have deduced the question and provided responses that addressed the question.

Comment: Nope. Never read anything by Connie Willis, far as I know. Why?

Comment: @user14111 Because then, the question would have jumped out screaming at you. If you don't want to read the book, then the answers will have to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the clear intimation is that she is pregnant.  In the [course of the story](https://fullenglishbooks.com/english-books/full-book-to-say-nothing-of-the-dog-read-online), I do not recall any other particular foreshadowing of this point, but that was the immediate conclusion I drew from reading the quoted passage.

Immediate preceding the passage quoted in the question is:

> “Pish-tosh!” she said. “You are fated to spend your life with me.” She handed me the kitten. “And Penwiper.”
>
> The kitten didn’t weigh anything. “Penwiper,” I said, and it looked up at me with gray-green eyes.
>
> “Mere,” it said, and began to purr, a very small purr. A purrlet.
>
> “Where did you get this kitten?” I said to Verity.
>
> “I stole it,” she said. “Don’t look like that. I intend to take it back. And Finch will never miss it.”

This appears to be another part of her roundabout way of saying that as they spend their lives together, it's not just going to be the *two* of them.

Comment: I read it again, and there is one scene abd a follow-up to it that _just might_ foreshadow this.  _If_ you are willing to stretch interpretation to the breaking point.

Comment: You know, now I read "Where did you get this kitten" with a note of panic in Ned's voice.

Answer (score 4):

No. When would they have had the opportunity? The novel chronicles practically every minute of Ned's life during his Victorian phase. They talked straight through their private rendezvous. And Willis makes it clear that Ned slept all night with the dog, not with Verity. Unless you want them to have a wild scene in a burning cathedral...?

Comment: This is the big conundrum that had me scratching my head. But Ms. Willis appears to imply something _quite_ different at the end. And that's where the question lies. There may be a big gap between the lines you are missing, hidden behind the kedgeree.

Comment: Spencer, I've read this book maybe five times over (and love the breakfast scene with the kedgeree). In a nutshell, Ned needed sleep more than sex. And if he'd had sex, he would have slept so well afterward that Willis would have had to remark on it. If Verity indulged herself in a bit of innuendo, it was all in good fun. After the novel ends, of course, the veil falls over their private life, but we can guess that they didn't lose any further time.

Comment: You've provided a reasonable answer but the question is here because of the last scene. Nevertheless, I was surprised that nobody took this line back in April 2018 when the question was posted. It's a bad idea to try and argue some of the specifics so I'll just give you your +1 and leave it at that.

Comment: What a pity! I was looking forward to an hour-by-hour analysis of Ned's and Verity's movements over the few days they were together, as Connie Willis can be relied on to have worked out the details. Incidentally, this is one of the few science fiction books that I've kept on my shelf. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: Anyway, "where did they find the time" is probably a different question than the one I'm asking, and probably one that will be problematical when asked about a time-travel story.